# apache reverse proxy hhtps

Tags: apache, https, reverse-proxy

Setting up apache reverse proxy
Client ==> Proxy ==> Server

This is on a windows machine on my local for testing have set an entry in my host file mapping the proxy dns to 127.0.0.1

### httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName <proxy Server>
     SSLEngine On
     SSLProxyEngine On
     ProxyRequests Off
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Proxy>
     SSLCertificateFile "<cert for proxy server>"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "<key for proxy server>"
     ProxyPass /  https://appserver.com/
     ProxyPassReverse /  https://appserver.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't see any errors in the error.log while starting. When I make a request https://proxy.com there is no entry in access.log or error.log.

Can anyone see an issue with in the config or give some ideas?
Thanks
Rahul

Comment: Modules loaded
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Comment: proxy requests is set to Off

Comment: ProxyRequests Off is the recommended for setting up reverse proxy. Apache site says "When using a reverse proxy (using the ProxyPass directive with ProxyRequests Off), access control is less critical because clients can only contact the hosts that you have specifically configured."

Comment: also tried with SSLProxyCheckPeerName and SSLProxyCheckPeerCN as off didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so it finally worked. Started from scratch
1. Added Listen 443 in httpd.conf it already had for port 80 (Listen 80)
2. Enabled modules one by one

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so 
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

3. Uncommented httpd-vhosts.conf in httpd.conf
4. Added the following in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin xyz@mail.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
ServerName <proxy Server>
ErrorLog "c:/Apache24/logs/error-ssl.log"
CustomLog "c:/Apache24/logs/access-ssl.log" common
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLEngine on
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

 SSLCertificateFile "<cert for proxy server>"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "<Key for proxy server>"

ProxyPass /  https://appserver.com/
ProxyPassReverse / https://appserver.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and it started working. Had tried so many things and had so many changes that starting from start made sense. Mostly was missing the Listen 443 in the httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

You only need the following to do an SSL proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName <proxy Server>
     SSLEngine On
     ProxyPass "/"  "http://www.example.com/"
     ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://www.example.com/"
     SSLCertificateFile "<cert for proxy server>"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "<key for proxy server>"
</VirtualHost>
```

The other stuff isnt necessary.

Comment: Hi Mike, Yes I have tried that no luck. I get "The site can't be reached". <appserver.com> refused to connect.